# Edit Xamarin Forms pages visually

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing a multiplatform app with Xamarin using Visual Studio on Mac, I do not know how can I edit the `MainPage.`xaml design, can I edit it using Xcode storyboard? How can I open the page in design mode?

Comment: There is not a visual designer for Xamarin Forms XAML.  You can use Hot Reload to visual XAML changes in real time, but there is no drag and drop designer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Design of XAML is not currently supported by Xamarin.Forms.

[Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload) doc here.

[Xamarin.Forms XAML Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/) will presumably be updated, if such a designer is added.

As a practical matter, instead look for .NET Maui to eventually have such a designer.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

The iOS Designer was deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.8, and removed in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9. The recommended way to build iOS user interfaces is directly on a Mac running Xcode's Interface Builder. For more information, see [Designing user interfaces with Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/). [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-quickstart?pivots=windows)

But this means you can not edit the **storyboard** file in the visual studio directly anymore. But the **.xaml** could not be edit by Visual Design all the time.